# Speed Up Python Video Player That Uses OpenCV and PyQt

Tags: python, performance, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to speed up a special purpose video player I wrote using Python, OpenCV and PyQt on a Windows platform.  The video player runs fine on my laptop with video files that are 1920x1080 at 30 frames per second, but runs slow with more challenging files, such as 4K (3840x2160).

The video player employs the following process:

- Read a frame (OpenCV)
- Convert the frame color scheme to RGB (OpenCV)
- Convert the image to a  QImage (PyQt)
- Convert the QImage to a Qpixmap (PyQt)
- Scale the QPixmap to fit in the QLabel (PyQt)
- Display the QPixmap in the QLabel (PyQt)

Frame rate is governed using QTimer.

`multiprocessing` is not a solution when using OpenCV because `cv2.VideoCapture` can’t be pickled.

Using the GPU also doesn’t appear to be helpful [from what I’ve read] because Cuda doesn’t read the frames, so there isn’t much else for Cuda to do.

I’m locked into using PyQt, but can trade out OpenCV if another solution works better.

The video player is interactive and needs to retain the capabilities to pause, play, use a slider to zip to a specific forward and abckwars, and to jump to a specific frame.

Are there any solutions to speeding up the processing so that I might be able to play 4K videos at normal speed?

Here is a minimalized script.  The QLabel is in a QMainWindow and the QLabel expands to the maximum size available.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSizePolicy, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QRect, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import sys, cv2


class Example():
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblVid = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblVid.setGeometry(QRect(4, 5, 791, 561))
        self.lblVid = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lblVid.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblVid, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.startVideo()
        
    def startVideo(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture('myVideo.mp4')
        fps = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        self.timer = QTimer()
        millisecs = int(1000.0 / fps)
        self.timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.nextFrameSlot)
        self.timer.start(millisecs)
        

    def nextFrameSlot(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = QImage(frame,frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
            pix = QPixmap.fromImage(img)            
            pix = pix.scaled(self.lblVid.width(), self.lblVid.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.lblVid.setPixmap(pix)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Example()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can't you use [QMediaPlayer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html)? If not, the [QTimer docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details) say: "It should be written in such a way that it always returns quickly". It might not be the case when you are performing I/O operations (reading the video). Have you seen that video players usually buffer the video? Maybe you need to do something like that.

Comment: QMediaPlayer will work fine. I forgot about QMediaPlayer.  It will be a significant amount of work to replace OpenCV with QMediaPlayer, but I think it will be a better player. Thanks!